# strlen() counts characters even after the null terminator

Tags: c, string-length

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
char a[100]="1234\0567"; //Answer: 6
int len=strlen(a);
printf("%d",len); 
}
```

This code prints 6 as the answer. Shouldn't it print 4 since strlen returns the count until the null character is encountered?

However when a space is included between \0 and 5. It returns 4 as the answer

```
char a[100]="1234\0 567"; //Answer: 4
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first version has the octal number `\056` not the `\0` character

Edit:
in the similar situations use `\000` octal sequence instead:

```
/* from your example*/ char a[100]="1234\000567";
```

Comment: or `char a[100]="1234\0" "567";`

Comment: @chux indeed :)

Answer (score 1):

The `\056` is a single character, with the octal ASCII code (56)<sub>8</sub>,  decimal - (46)<sub>10</sub>.